# "navbar-button" does not align on collapse (mobile view)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button on the navbar, as the code below:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
     <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Login</button></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Working example: http://www.bootply.com/IgS3X7CMs8#

So, the problem is, when I see in the mobile view, the button is in the left margin, not aligned with the other links.

Is there a way to align it? preferably with boostrap classes (without setting a fixed margin-left to the component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to set a margin to the button.

```
.navbar-btn { margin-left: 15px }
```

and it will be aligned with the other elements.
Of course, you would need to specify the breakpoint, at which the mobile view is present.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { .navbar-btn { margin-left: 15px; } }
```

Comment: I've searched for something in bootstrap, no luck. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="myBtn"><div class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Login</div</a>

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
  a#mybtn {
    margin: 8px 0px 10px 16px;
    padding: 0;
  } 
}

a#myBtn {
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That does the trick for mobile (You see there's a bigger vertical gap between the button and the other links). And it messes up with the normal view: http://www.bootply.com/wQbyKTTixG